# Why won't my script run when attemping to make a toggle on and off key?

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to make an autohotkey script that loops but only when the script is toggled on, how can i pull this off? this one just doesnt run and idk why

```
g::
Suspend
Pause
return

Count := 1

Loop {

  if (Count = 1){
    Send {s down}
    Send {a down}
    Send {d up}
    Count := Count + 1
  }else if (Count = 1000){
    Send {a up}
    Send {d down}
    Count := Count + 1
  }else if (Count = 2000){
    Count := 1
  }else{
    Count := Count + 1
  }


  Sleep, 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure why you're using `Suspend`.  `Pause` should be sufficient to do what you're looking for.  `Suspend` suspends all hotkeys (except the g hotkey in this case because it's the first line in the hotkey), whereas `Pause` pauses the current thread.  And second of all, you have your loop after the hotkey.  The auto-execute section of any autohotkey script is only from the top to the first hotkey, so you need to put the loop first, then the hotkey.  Here is the revised code:

```
Count := 1

Loop {

  if (Count = 1){
    Send {s down}
    Send {a down}
    Send {d up}
    Count := Count + 1
  }else if (Count = 1000){
    Send {a up}
    Send {d down}
    Count := Count + 1
  }else if (Count = 2000){
    Count := 1
  }else{
    Count := Count + 1
  }


  Sleep, 10
}

g::
Pause
return
```

Comment: [`Suspend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm#Remarks) wouldn't suspend the `g` hotkey, since its very first line is the `Suspend` command.

Comment: Good catch!  Thank you